# Solving palindromic 'Triangle Quest' puzzle in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, palindrome

I'm trying to solve this programming puzzle:

> You are given a positive integer N (0 < N < 10). Your task is to print a
>   palindromic triangle of size N.
>
> For example, a palindromic triangle of size 5 is:
>
> ```
> 1
> 121
> 12321
> 1234321
> 123454321
> ```
>
> You can't take more than two lines. You have to complete the code
>   using exactly one print statement.
>
> Note: Using anything related to strings will give a score of 0. Using
>   more than one for-statement will give a score of 0.

I can think only of 'dumb' way to do this:

```
for i in range(1, N+1):
    print([0, 1, 121, 12321, 1234321, 123454321, 12345654321, 1234567654321, 123456787654321, 12345678987654321][i])
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Somehow, there is now way to get a non-zero score, as printing is related to strings.

Comment: Note that 121 = 11 * 11, 12321 = 111 * 111 etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended up doing the following (thanks @raina77ow for the idea):

```
for i in range(1, N+1):
    print((111111111//(10**(9-i)))**2)
```

Comment: Slightly better way: `print((10**i//9)**2)`.

Answer (score 12):

```
for i in range(1,int(input())+1):
   print(int((10**i-1)/9)**2)

1 -> (   10 - 1) / 9 =    1,    1 *    1 = 1
2 -> (  100 - 1) / 9 =   11,   11 *   11 = 121
3 -> ( 1000 - 1) / 9 =  111,  111 *  111 = 12321
4 -> (10000 - 1) / 9 = 1111, 1111 * 1111 = 1234321
```

Answer (score 7):

```
for i in range(1,6):
    print (((10 ** i - 1) // 9) ** 2)
```

Here's a wtf one liner:

```
f=lambda n:n and[f(n-1),print((10**n//9)**2),range(1,n+1)];f(5)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
def palindrome(N):
    for i in range(1, N + 1):
        print(int('1' * i)**2)

palindrome(int(input()))
```

- 1 * 1 = 1
- 11 * 11 = 121
- 111 * 111 = 12321

Comment: If the coding challenge rules exclude strings, then this solution will fail.

Answer (score 1):

```
  for i in range(1,int(input())+1): #More than 2 lines will result in 0 score. Do not leave a blank line also
    print(''.join(list(map(lambda x:str(x),list(range(i+1))[1:]))+list(map(lambda x:str(x),list(reversed(list(range(i))[1:]))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple string-less version:

```
for i in range(1, int(input()) + 1):
    print(sum(list(map(lambda x: 10 ** x, range(i)))) ** 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Code golfing and taking advice of simon and rain:

```
set(map(lambda x:print((10**x//9)**2),range(1,N+1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1, N + 1):
    print(*list(range(1, i + 1)) + list(range(i - 1, 0, -1)), sep = None)
```

Comment: This separates the numbers by space (and using `sep=""` is not allowed)

Comment: @planetp, you are correct that it separates the numbers by space, but the OP didn't specify that separating the numbers by space isn't allowed - after all, the answer is still a palindromic triangle, just with spaces :) however, even if it is not valid, I thought it was worth including because it is potentially more understandable than the math answers :)

Comment: Way late to the party, but...

```python
reduce(lambda x, y: x*10 + y, list(range(1, i + 1)) + list(range(i - 1, 0, -1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because every solution offered so far involves range() which I feel is overused in Python code:

```
from math import log10

i = 1
while (N > log10(i)): print(i**2); i = i * 10 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to print in list format using below:

```
    for i in range(1,5):
        print [j for j in range(1,i+1) ], [j for j in range(i-1,0,-1) ]
```

Result:

```
[1] []
[1, 2] [1]
[1, 2, 3] [2, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4] [3, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code should work. I have used the most basic method, so that most people are going to understand it:

```
  N = int(input())
  arr = []
  for i in range(1,N+1):
         arr.append(i)
         print(arr+arr[-2: :-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been asked a while ago, but I just stumbled upon this exercise and found an alternative and elegant solution to it.

As suggested by @raina77ow, we know that `11 * 11 = 121`, `111 * 111 = 12321` and so on.
But we also know that:

```
2**1 - 1 = 1 (is 1 in binary)
2**2 - 1 = 3 (is 11 in binary)
2**3 - 1 = 7 (is 111 in binary)
2**4 - 1 = 15 (is 1111 in binary)
etc.
```

Now, by doing `bin(15)` you get `0b1111` and I hate that I had to transform it to integer using slicing, but I found no other method.

So, using the above, this is my solution:

```
for i in range(1,int(input())+1):  # given line
    print(int(bin(2**i - 1)[2:])**2)
```

Comment: This is an interesting alternative solution. I'm not sure why it was voted down, but it might be less efficient because of the conversion and array. You'd have to run timing tests to see.

Comment: @bikemule all tests passed on their website. I guess stricter test cases could show a difference. Thanks for your evaluation!

Answer (score -1):

```
    for i in range(2,int(raw_input())+2): 
        print ''.join(([unicode(k) for k in range(1,i)]))+""+''.join(([unicode(k) for k in range(i-2,0,-1)]))
        print ''.join(map(unicode,range(1,i)))+""+''.join(map(unicode,range(i-2,0,-1)))
```

I hope it will help.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```
prefix = ''
suffix = ''

for i in range(1,n):
    middle = str(i)
    string = prefix + middle + suffix
    print(string)

    prefix = prefix + str(i)
    suffix = ''.join(reversed(prefix))
```

Comment: @jkdev what was wrong with my code, why the down vote

Comment: I only added “Use this code:” before the code block. No edits to the code block itself.

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in range(1,int(input())+1):
    print(int(str('1'*i))**2)
```

Basically on each iteration, the number '1' in string is multiplied by i times then converted to an integer then squared. So e.g.

On the 3rd iteration --> output = 111^2 = 12321

Edit: Noticed constraints was to answer with str() function

So we have a sequence 1, 11, 111, 1111
nth = an + (a(r^(n-1) - 1)) / (r - 1) where |r > 1|

therefore, solution;

```
for i in range(1,int(input())+1):
    print(pow((((10**i - 10))//9) + 1, 2))
```

Answer (score -1):

Putting in my two cents worth, using unpacking of range

```
    for i in range(1, int(input()) + 1):
        print (*range(1, i+1), *range(i-1, 0, -1))
```

Just noticed [Keith Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4473405/keith-hall) has a very similar solution.   He should get original credit for this.

Answer (score -1):

***Easy Way for this***

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
n = int(input())
st = ''
st2 = ''
for i in range(1,n+1):
    st += str(i)
    if i==0:
        print(st)
    else:
        st2 = str(i-1) + st2
        print(st+st2.rstrip('0'))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please consider adding some description explaining how it solves the problem or add comments in the source code at appropriate places.